# System Events AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I created a program that uses "System Events" and I have lots of error messages when it "runs". Two error messages 1): "is not allowed to send keystrokes." and 2): "is not allowed to send keystrokes", is displayed when the program uses "keystrokes" or "key code" with "System Events". I have authorized the AppleScript program in the "Security and Privacy" section and error messages always appear. How to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If this is a script application, is it code signed or otherwise read only?

Comment: Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Accessibility and delete your application and then add it again. You should grant to your application permissions **to control your computer**.